# Experience Cloud Login Navigation using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, login, experience-cloud

We have a custom LWC Login page under an experience builder site, which uses a custom apex controller and `site.login` method to authenticate the user.

Apex Authentication code :

```
ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

        if(pageRef != null){
            system.debug(pageRef);
         return pageRef.getUrl();
        }
```

After the user is authenticated, pageRef is sent back to LWC as string with session.

In LWC, I need to navigate user to home page after logging in, but navigationMixin is opening the URL is new tab instead of refreshing current page.

LWC Code to Navigate:

```
navigateToWebPage(url) {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        "type": "standard__webPage",
        "attributes": {
            "url": url
        }
    });
}
```

I also tried `window.location.href` but that does not navigate the user at all.

How do I redirect the user to the home page after they are authenticated with session in Experience cloud LWC?

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of pages in Salesforce.

- **recordPage** - standard__recordPage
- **objectPage** - standard__objectPage
- **for URL** - standard__webPage home page, chatter or any
  standard/custom pages - standard__namedPage
- and many more...

Please update your code with below

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'home' // add apiname of page
            },
        });
```

[image]

Refer below article for more information -
https://mukulmahawariya11.medium.com/navigation-in-salesforce-communities-ad6838488166

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it gives error `a preNavigate hook listener blocked` and as this is a page within experience cloud, I added comm__namedPage instead of standard.

Comment: can you tell did it worked or not?

Comment: it did not, as I mentioned it gives that hook listener error and it cannot be `standard` since the Home page is within community.

Answer (score 0):

If your LWC is headless then you can use invoke() method like below

```
@api invoke(){
  window.location.href = url   //your url value
}
```

Comment: Navigating the user to the homepage after login does not sound headless to me. So while this may be an answer to _a_ question, I don't think that this answers _this_ question.

Comment: @DerekF correct, this won't work. I tried navigationMixin as well but that always opens the page in new tab and doesn't redirect user.